# ASP.net mvc API get request and JSON data

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, api

Trying to call a weather API using a service for asp.net mvc.

I have a `Weather` class that looks like this:

```
public class Weather
{
    public string main { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

The method I am using to make the `GET` request looks like this:

```
    async public static Task<List<Weather>> GetWeather()
    {
        List<Weather> weatherData = new List<Weather>();

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&APPID=[MYKEY]");

        HttpContent content = response.Content;

        string data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

The URI I'm requesting returns JSON objects.

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": 139,
    "lat": 35
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 804,
      "main": "Clouds",
      "description": "overcast clouds",
      "icon": "04n"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 299.26,
    "pressure": 1007,
    "humidity": 83,
    "temp_min": 296.15,
    "temp_max": 301.15
  },
  "visibility": 16093,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 5.1,
    "deg": 330,
    "gust": 7.2
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 90
  },
  "dt": 1533638820,
  "sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 7618,
    "message": 0.0028,
    "country": "JP",
    "sunrise": 1533585473,
    "sunset": 1533634868
  },
  "id": 1851632,
  "name": "Shuzenji",
  "cod": 200
}
```

I want to access the `"weather"` object and extract the properties `main` and `description` and in my `GetWeather` return a list where the weather properties from the `JSON` object match the properties in my `class Weather`.

I'm lost on what to do with the string `data` and how to get the JSON data into my `List<Weather>`.

EDIT

Tried to use `JObject.Parse()` as mentioned in the answer below but get an error `Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference` when trying to print it to the console.

```
async public static Task<List<Weather>> GetWeather()
        {

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&APPID=[MYKEY]");

            HttpContent content = response.Content;

            string data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            dynamic d = JObject.Parse(data);
            var main = d.main.ToString();
            var description = d.description.ToString();

            var weatherData = new List<Weather>
            {
                new Weather { Main = main,
                              Description = description }
            };

            Console.WriteLine(weatherData);

            return weatherData;
        }
```

Comment: You can use [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/) to map json data into c# classes.

Answer (score 3):

Steps to access value of description from your json

Create model class for given json string, Visual studio provided option for it

**Edit -> Paste special -> Paste JSON As class**

class look like

```
public class MyClass
{
    public class Coord {
       public int lon { get; set; }
       public int lat { get; set; } }

    public class Weather {
       public int id { get; set; }
       public string main { get; set; }
       public string description { get; set; }
       public string icon { get; set; } }
 ...
```

Use **[NewtonSoft.JSON](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)** library to deserialize json

```
MyClass temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass >(jsonString);
```

Now you can access description property of Weather class by

```
string output = temp.Weather.description
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to look into **deserializing** the json. The easiest way for an example (although not as maintainable) would be to dump the json into a dynamic and pull the fields you want;

```
dynamic d = JObject.Parse(data);
var description = d.description.ToString();
```

If you create classes to match the JSON (it looks like your Weather class doesn't quite match - main is a nested object and not a string) then you can use **Json.DeserializeObject< Weather >(data)**

Comment: Edited question

Comment: @anaximander - Assuming the JSON you have posted is correct - you do not have a 'description' property in it? That would explain the null reference...

Comment: @anaximander - Oh sorry i see it now, you will want d.weather.description

Comment: @anaximander - each property with a { ... } is a new object, so will need referenced with a dot

Comment: Keep running into new errors. Unhandled exception: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray. Not used to do this with C#, normally do it in expressJS, so kinda clueless on how to handle the data.

Comment: @anaximander - Sorry, I am replying too quickly, I didn't notice that it was an array, you will actually want d.weather[0].description

Comment: @anaximander the [ ] brackets represent an ARRAY, so this can contain a number of elements, you have to reference the 0

Comment: Alright, figures. Getting : System.Collections.Generic.List`1[APITest.Weather] now, looks like it is doing what its supposed to.